# Soft разработчика

Tags: linux, laravel, apache, сервер

Мои попытки "оседлать" Vagrant и Homestead в течение пару дней закончились разочарованием и множеством глюков этих программ. Потратив время на поиск решений , и начитавшись советов решил , что для современной разработки желательно переформатировать свой SSD и начать с чистого листа. Подскажите как создать близкую к идеальной среду разработчика ? Какие ОС и в какой последовательности установить на ПК ? Знаком со всеми , хотя до сих пор активно использовал Windows , виртуальные образы, платный хостинг, Git, Heroku, Bitbacket. Начав познавать Laravel понял что нужно всё менять. Помогите !

Comment: Если привыкли к винде - оставайтесь на винде. Ставьте на виртуалку (я советую vmware) ubuntu server (он без GUI - она не нужна, пишем код в винде). Потом там есть функция "Shared Folders" - шарим папку с кодом из винды в линуксовую машину. После этого код пишем на винде - а запускаем в линуксе на виртуалке - не нужно будет заморачиваться с копированием кода. Для управления линухом лучше подключаться по SSH - так удобней.

Comment: Спасибо. А Server lang  рус или eng ?

Comment: Это вопрос "вкусовщины", некоторые рекомендуют ставить язык на котором вы говорите (проще понять), а я допустим рекомендую ставить всегда английский (проще найти ответ за счёт того, что англоязычных форумов проще).

Comment: @Taypfoon одназначно `eng` - так ошибки потом гуглить легче

Answer (score 0):

Многие веб разработчики сталкиваются с данной проблемой, у всех разные, вкусы однако по моему опыту следуют установить следующее.

1) Git или SVN(При работе вы сможете отследить свои ошибки и быстрее отменить код,деля процесс разработки на стадии. Как пример пилили на Jquery,отказались, перескочили на Angular)

2)Среды виртуализации(lxc,vagrant,doker).Причина их выбора банальна, возможность переноса конфигурации на сервер и несвместимость ПО для разработки с софтом операционной системы. Особенно актуально это для Ruby и Python.

3) Установите IDE (Jetbrains,Netbeans,Visual Studio)

По поводу ваших ошибок с Homestead.
Типичные проблемы:

1) Не добавлен путь до ключа авторизации ssh

2) Камень не поддерживает виртуализацию или она не включена

3) Ошибка операционой ситемы Windows(Ник не на английском, а на русском или других языках)

Все учебники можете найти https://laracasts.com/

Или скачать их у друзей с торрент файла

К тому же если уж совсем лагает, есть возможность запустить laravel из консоли

`php artisan serve --port=8080`

Из ОС удобней использовать Unix и Linux подобные, так как винда глючна в вопросах фреймвоков. Лично я использую Ubuntu/Debian

Comment: Ошибка с Homestead https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/888933/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-vagrant-error  До ошибки день работало. Потом рухнуло . Похожие глюки и с Homestead . Оттого и озадачился полной перезагрузкой и уходом от Windows.

Comment: @Taypfoon похоже что вы просто плохо разбираетесь, а не глюки, в вашем вопросе нет глюка судя по скрину

Comment: Вообще не разбираюсь. Только начал разбираться. И сразу ошибки. А как исправить ошибку что на скрине ?

Comment: @YaroslavMolchan посоветовал бы автору маломальски освоить  одну из ос ( Win или *nix) пройти курс по админке хотяб. Кстати, что такое Linux подобная ОС, первый раз слышу.

Comment: Android, Mac OS есть разработки компании "Цезарь". Частные сборки из Linux from scratch

Comment: К тому же я пытаюсь помочь, хотел вагрант файл посмотреть. Пусть хотя бы trysty поднимет